# Angular custom validator not returning error code

Tags: angular, customvalidator

Hi guys I have created custom validator for my form and its working fine - detecting the error as expected but when it does detect it the errors in FormGroup object is empty but valid is properly set to false

```js
export function ValidateBody(control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors {
  if (control.value.length < 3) return { tooShort: true };
  if (control.value.length > 50) return { tooLong: true };
  if (/[^a-zA-Z0-9 \-\/]/.test(control.value)) return { invalidChar: true };
  return null;
}
```

```js
export class FormQuestionComponent {
  @Input() question: FormData<any>;
  @Input() form: FormGroup;
  get isValid() {
    if (!this.form.controls[this.question.key].valid)
      console.log(this.form.errors);
    return this.form.controls[this.question.key].valid;
  }
}
```

I have no idea why I'm getting null in the console even when form is invalid. I have also tried to make inputs validated by build in Validators valid but still no errors given.

Comment: This does not have enough code to reproduce the issue.. for example, where is this validator?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Where have you registered custom Validator?